# Define a service with lazy loading logger in symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, interface, lazy-loading

How to inject in a Symfony service the Logger component in lazy mode using DI.  My intention is to log information in some methods.  The logger instance must be created at the first time is used.

Something like this:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class XxxService{
    private $logger;

    public function some_method(){
      echo "method without logging"
      return $this;
    }

    private function _log($text){
        if(!$this->logger) $this->logger = new LoggerInterface(); //wrong approach creating object from Interface
        $this->logger->info($text)
    }

    public function method_withlog(){
        $this->_log("text logged")
        return $this;
    }
}

(new XxxService()))
    ->some_method()
    ->method_withlog() //here is created
    ->some_method()->method_withlog();
```

Comment: Based on the tags I am assuming that you are using the Symfony DI container?  In which case you just use the [lazy flag](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) when you define the service.  Another approach might be to use a service locator.  Keep in mind that a service such as a logger is almost always going to be instantiated regardless so there is not much point in making it lazy.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad. Yes I'm using Symfony 5. Using the lazy flag it injects a proxy instance? thus if I call method_withlog() it will instantiate the real object?

Comment: Yes.  If you inject a logger proxy then as soon as you attempt to use the logger it will instantiate the actual logger.